# How to animate a swinging rope?

Tags: math, physics

Swinging ropes are commonly found in platform video games where the player jumps on a rope to reach an adjacent platform or what not.

What math is involved in making this possible. I am thinking of somehow having the end of the rope follow the outline of a circle while having the rope itself create waves via the sine function.

Comment: The end of the rope will only trace a circle if the rope is permanently taut. That makes sense for a swinging rigid bar, but not for a rope.

Comment: That did occur to me. I was thinking that I could have each point on the line trace a smaller circle with an incrementally longer delay. That might actually work

Comment: Are you looking to make the rope rigid like the old Mario games, or "floppy" like a real rope?

Comment: @JonathanM, The delay should take care of the "floppy" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something physically accurate, I would go for a mass--spring model:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rope_physics/17006/

Comment: When I click that link I get "There was an error while handling your request."  Please check it.

Comment: checked. Link works fine for me and I don't see any reason it shouldn't for anyone else.